# PyQGIS Push selected feature to identification results panel

Tags: pyqgis, vector-tiles, identify

I have selected feature on vector tile layer loaded from [https://cdn.kadastr.live/tiles/maps/kadastr/land_polygons/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf](https://cdn.kadastr.live/tiles/maps/kadastr/land_polygons/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.pbf)

How do I make its attributes appear in the identification results panel as if I clicked on it with the identification tool?